# The object () is not applicable

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am writing a very simple program for Pascal's triangle in scheme (exercise from SICP). I wrote this code and its getting an error message `The object () is not applicable.`

```lisp
  (define (pascal-triangle n)
    (define (get-value list position)
      (define (get-sum-iter prevList counter)(
        cond 
          ((= counter (- position 1)) 
             (+ (car prevList) (car (cdr prevList))))
          (else (get-sum-iter (cdr prevList) (+ counter 1))) 
      ))
      (get-sum-iter list 0)
    )
    (define (create-list prevList size)
      (define (create-list-iter currList counter)(
        cond 
          ((or (= counter (- size 1)) 
               (= counter 0)) 
             (create-list-iter (cons 1 currList) (- counter 1)))
          ((> counter 0) 
              create-list-iter 
              (cons (get-value prevList counter) 
                    currList) 
              (- counter 1))
          (else currList)
      ))
      (create-list-iter () (- size 1))
    )
    (define (pascal-triangle-iter resultList counter)
      (cond 
        ((> counter n) resultList)
        (else 
          (pascal-triangle-iter 
            (cons create-list 
                  ((cond 
                       ((null? resultList) resultList) 
                       (else (car resultList))) 
                    counter)
                  resultList) 
            (+ counter 1)))
      )
    )
    (pascal-triangle-iter () 1)
  )
```

In my function definition of `pascal-triangle-iter` I expect the first parameter to be a list of list. but when I'm calling it I am just passing an empty list and not list of list. My guess is that this is the cause of the error `The object () is not applicable` But when how do I initialize and empty list of list?

Comment: Replace `(pascal-triangle-iter () 1)` with `((pascal-triangle-iter (list) 1)` and read [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)

Comment: You have lots of misplaced parentheses.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't understand your answer/comment. I changed the line to `(pascal-triangle-iter (list) 1)` but it made no difference.

Comment: @Barmar are you referring to my code? My code compiles so I don't think there are missing / misplaced parentheses.

Comment: But it doesn't run correctly because the parentheses are misplaced.

Comment: `(cons create-list ...` should be `(cons (create-list ...` Otherwise you're putting the `create-list` procedure in the cons, not calling the function.

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty list of lists in Scheme; either a list is empty, or it isn't. `()` is not self-evaluating in Scheme (it is in Common Lisp), so you need to quote it if you want an empty list literal: `'()`. That said, there are at least two errors in placement of parentheses that will derail your code. You will help yourself by working on your code formatting; SICP code is not formatted this way; look at the way idiomatic Scheme is formatted, and emulate that. Lisp style is fairly consistent, and has evolved that way for good reasons.

Comment: @adabsurdum There is indeed an empty list of lists in Scheme. That same object is also an empty list of integers, an empty list of strings, and an empty list of elephants.  A function working strictly with lists-of-lists can have empty lists occurring in it, and considers those to be empty lists of lists.

Comment: @Kaz -- Empty lists have a type distinct from that of other lists in Scheme: ["The empty list is a special object of its own type. It is not a pair. It has no elements and its length is zero."](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.9) Conceptually you may have empty lists of elephants, but Scheme does not have those unless you implement your own type system.

Comment: @adabsurdum: Scheme does not have non-empty lists of elephants either. Indeed it has empty lists of elephants in precisely the same sense it has lists of elephants.  Also `(list? '())`: `()` is not a *pair*: it is a list.

Comment: @tfb It is a vacuous truth in mathematics that all the objects in an empty set have whatever property you want. "Every X in list L is an elephant" is a true proposition, if L is empty.  Not being able to construct a non-empty list of elephants is no impediment against an empty list of elephants.

Comment: @adabsurdum If you have an empty list `X` in Scheme, you can use it as the tail of a new list, which contains items of any type, e.g. `(cons 42 X)` is valid as is `(cons "abc" X)` or `(cons '(a b c) X)`, where the last one is a list of lists. The empty list has a representation, but that representation is part of the list type; the empty list satisfies `list?` predicate just like a non-empty one. Neither case says anything about the element type. A list being of certain elements is determined by its contents. Due to a vacuous truth, the objects in an empty list have any property you wish.

Comment: @Kaz: yes, sorry, I was trying to agree with you!  A list is a list of anything, elephants are a thing and so a list (including the empty list) is a list of elephants.  It's not *exclusively* a list of elephants (there must be a type-theory term for that).  Anyway: yes, you are correct that `()` is the empty list of lists.

Comment: @tfb -- There is no way _within Scheme_ to distinguish between an empty list and an empty list of lists. Conceptually, you may _imagine_ an empty list of lists, but the Scheme empty list can't contain anything, per the Standards. You may construct lists of objects by placing the empty list in the tail of a cons. OP was concerned that passing a plain empty list in place of an empty list of lists was the source of their error; this seemed to be a confusion about the nature of empty lists in Scheme, hence my first comment to OP.

Comment: @adabsurdum: precisely: if there is no way to distinguish between the two things *they are operationally the same thing* (and actually the same thing in the case of any Lisp I know of).  The empty list is an empty list of *any type at all* in just the same way that the empty set is the empty set of any thing at all.  Thanks also for the lesson in how to construct lists: it's always nice to be patronised.

Comment: @tfb -- hmmm. I did not mean to patronise, but it seems that we are talking past each other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone specially @barmar and @adabsurdum to helping me. The problem was the my parenthesis were off. The list construction was fine. The following code works fine for me (MIT Scheme on Mac OS)

```lisp
; pascal triangle recursive
(define (pascal-triangle n)
  (define (get-value list position)
    (define (get-sum-iter prevList counter)(
      cond 
        ((= counter (- position 1)) (+ (car prevList) (car (cdr prevList))))
        (else (get-sum-iter (cdr prevList) (+ counter 1))) 
    ))
    (get-sum-iter list 0)
  )
  (define (create-list prevList size)
    (define (create-list-iter currList counter)(
      cond 
        ((or (= counter (- size 1)) (= counter 0)) (create-list-iter (cons 1 currList) (- counter 1)))
        ((> counter 0) (create-list-iter (cons (get-value prevList counter) currList) (- counter 1)))
        (else currList)
    ))
    (create-list-iter '() (- size 1))
  )
  (define (emptyOrFirst list)(
    cond 
    ((null? list) '())
    (else (car list))
  ))
 (define (pascal-triangle-iter resultList counter)
    (cond 
      ((> counter n) resultList)
      (else (pascal-triangle-iter (cons (create-list (emptyOrFirst resultList) counter) resultList) (+ counter 1)))
    )
  )
  (pascal-triangle-iter '() 1)
)
```